# Terminate multi-line key, value inputs to a dictionary by a user defined keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, while-loop

I am having issues with breaking from a multi-line addition to a dictionary. The task requires adding multiple lines of **Product,Quantity** inputs into a 'Cart' dictionary. The addition to dictionary should stop by a keyword 'show' or something similar which results in printing added elements of the dictionary. I have been able to initiate multi-line inputs to the cart dictionary but can't get the addition to stop by 'show' keyword.

Here's a portion of my code for reference:

```
class cart():
 pcart = {}

 def __init__(self,name):
  self.name = name

 def Show_Cart(self):
  print(self.pcart)

 def Add_Item(self):
  print('Adding your items and quantities')
  p,q = input().rpartition(' ')[::2]
  while q.lower() != 'show':
   self.pcart[p] = q
   if q.lower() == 'show':
    self.Show_Cart()

My_Cart = cart(input('Name of your cart:'))
print('Choose from the following options:')
status = int(input('1:Add Item  2:Remove Item'))

if status == 1:
 My_Cart.Add_Item()
```

EDIT-
As pointed out by @andrew_reece , the code above wouldnt get to Show_Cart function ever. I then tweaked it a bit and used **While True** condition to loop over the function operation and use an Else condition to break when  'Show' keyword appears. Here's my final code-

```
class cart():
  pcart = {}

  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

  def Show_Cart(self):
    print(self.pcart)
    Main()

  def Add_Item(self):
    print('Adding your items and quantities')
    while True:
      p,q = input().rpartition(' ')[::2]
      if q.lower() != 'show':
        self.pcart[p] = q
      else:
        self.Show_Cart()
        break

  def Remove_Item(self):
    print('Your cart contents are :' ,self.pcart)
    print('What all do you want to remove?')
    while True:
      p = input()
      if p.lower() != 'show':
        del self.pcart[p]
      else:
        self.Show_Cart()
        break


def Main():
  status = int(input('1:Add Item  2:Remove Item'))

  if status == 1:
    My_Cart.Add_Item()
  elif status == 2:
    My_Cart.Remove_Item()

My_Cart = cart(input('Name of your cart:'))
print('Choose from the following options:')
Main()
```

The code now works. However I am still wondering if using **While True** is a pythonic way to do things?

Comment: It doesn't look like `q` changes in your loop.

Comment: You'll also never reach `Show_Cart()` the way you have it set up.  If `q.lower() == 'show'`, the `while` loop will exit before it can call `Show_Cart()`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, 'Show' keyword would be saved in q variable once the input is rpartitioned

Comment: @andrew_reece, Added the final code in the edit which works. However i don't know if While True is a good approach to programing?

Comment: I'd say it is not at all pythonic. Python should always be obvious. `While True` obviously runs forever. Except here it doesn't. Move the `if` condition into the `while` statement.

Comment: Thanks @bendl! Here's the link to a more modifed code which removes the While True condition- https://repl.it/KYIi/18. Your inputs are appreciated!